# is xml better than sql file in liquibase changeset

Tags: liquibase

I think that XML files are more clear to read, but does it have advantage over SQL format. I found some info [here] (http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/liquibase-sql-vs-xml-command-changesets), but I would nice to hear others voices.

Comment: This link is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer using xml file because it's more abstract. For example you can define column type by VARCHAR/java.sql.Types.VARCHAR and liquibase will replace that by default configuration for target database - so it is not database specific. But if you have some database specifics (like plsql) then I'm using `.sql` files and loading them with `sqlFile` change.

Answer (score 2):

One of the primary reasons that Datical chose Liquibase as the core of our product was that the XML gave us the ability to look at the changelog in a programmatic way, allowing us to do things like forecasting the changes that would be made before they are applied to a database, and the ability to write rules against the changelog. If used with care, XML can give you a database-independent way of managing db changes also.